# Text input with currency icon in the center

Tags: css

Is it possible without JavaScript to make a text input element for currency where there is a currency icon always at the center (but it adjusts according to the number of digits)?

Something like

[image]

Comment: Can the currency be a float, or you want just integers?

Comment: What are your tries? your code to debug? Is this a problem or a request?

Comment: @underflow integers. @Leandro Bardelli I tried to do it with `flex` and then 2 child elements `span` and `input` but realized that the input has default width. So it is both problem and request I believe? Should I at least put my code attempt in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer:

Yes, it is

### Long Answer:

If you don't want to go through JS, you'll have to "mimic" an input by using an editable span.
The following code achieves it (what you requested):

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.currency-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 10em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.currency-input {
  cursor: text;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="currency-container">
  <div class="center-container">
    <span>$</span>
    <span class="currency-input" role="textbox" contenteditable>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is nice, It's almost what I meant but is it possible to make the entire box same width? The border around should stay the same, only the text inside moves

Comment: Found a better technique, kindly check the new code

Comment: This is amazing! But I think there is no escape from JS if I want to limit the number of characters when using `contenteditable` right? With text input I can use `maxlength`. Here I think I will need to limit it with JS (For example if I only want to allow 4 digits). But since it was not part of the question, it is still the accepted one, thank you

Comment: Indeed, setting a max length on a non-input element will need a use of JS. However you can use things like `overflow` and `text-overflow` to hide the "additional" digits, but they will still be present in the input. Anyways, thank you for the votes!